# python: py2exe cryptography Multibackend cannot be initialized with no backends

Tags: python, python-2.7, py2exe, python-cryptography

I am using python 2.7.11 on windows 7 64bit with **py2exe 0.6.9**, I got the following error after running the `.exe` file.

> ValueError: Multibackend cannot be initialized with no backends.
>
> If you are seeing this error when trying to use `default_backend()` please try uninstalling and reinstalling cryptography.

Answer (score 0):

i wrote bellow code then the problem has been solved.

```
def patch_crypto_be_discovery():

"""
Monkey patches cryptography's backend detection.
Objective: support pyinstaller freezing.
"""

from cryptography.hazmat import backends

try:
    from cryptography.hazmat.backends.commoncrypto.backend import backend as be_cc
except ImportError:
    be_cc = None

try:
    from cryptography.hazmat.backends.openssl.backend import backend as be_ossl
except ImportError:
    be_ossl = None

backends._available_backends_list = [
    be for be in (be_cc, be_ossl) if be is not None
]

patch_crypto_be_discovery()
```